# How to display project-specific message at the beginning of an sbt shell session?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to display a project-specific message at the start of an **sbt** (not Scala) session, similar to the one displayed when starting up the Scala REPL. It would be some sort of help message, but for commands or flows that are specific to that project.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

Is there a built-in way to do this or an sbt plugin for it? If not, how else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a dummy setting value as a way to access the SBT logger.

```
val welcomeMessage = settingKey[Unit]("Welcome message")

welcomeMessage := {
  sLog.value.info("<some message here>")
}
```

Note:

- this message will be displayed whenever SBT is run, not just when calling it to get to the SBT prompt.
- it's may not be the last message to be displayed

---

If the desire is to show a message when accessing the Scala console rather than the SBT prompt then there is more direct support.  The `initialCommands` setting allows you to set a snippet of code that is run when the Scala console is first entered which could include printing some messages.

[SBT docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Scala.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm interested in displaying a message when the sbt, not the Scala, console is started. So, just after someone executes the `sbt` command.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Answer updated for printing messages when entering SBT, at least with the best strategy I know how to do so.

Comment: Feels a bit like a hack, but until someone else comes up with a better solution, I'll go with this one. Thanks!